# rails unit test fails "undefined method 'request='"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run this unit test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "my action works" do
     get(:my_action, {'url' => "http://localhost:8090/"})
   end
end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'request=' for #<MyController:0x5150896>
```

Any idea?

EDIT this action only has POST and not GET but I see the same results when I change to post in the unit test

Comment: Can you access the controller normally? Can you post the code for it?

Comment: yes the web site works well in a browser. this reproduce also with an empty action in the controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen this happen when the name of the controller in the test is misspelled.  Are you sure that for this example the controller is named MyController?

Comment: the action name is MyControllers (plural) which alignes with all otehr auto generated unit tests which use singular also. When I change the test name to something else I get "@controller is null" which means that before the change it could at least find the controller

Comment: you are right, I thought it is enough to use the default generated names, but I learned from here that there is a different convention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743059/how-do-i-get-rid-of-controller-is-nil-error-in-my-tests

Answer (score 10):

This will happen if you've forgotten to inherit from ApplicationController or some derivative thereof...

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two reasons:

1. It means you haven't required the controllers file. or
2. You have a typo in the name that is instantiating the a non 
   controller for the @controller variable in the test.

Cross check at your test file, this will surly solve your problem.